# Deploying two different daemonsets with the same List manifest

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, containers, daemonset

I have a scenario where I need to deploy one pod on every node in my cluster so that it can watch certain behaviour (like, whether the pod gets created, terminated properly or not). Since, I've already one DaemonSet running inside my cluster, I wanted to add one more DaemonSet using the available config to the List resource,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
metadata:
  name: Daemonset-deploy
  namespace: test-ns
items:
  - kind: DaemonSet
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    metadata:
      name: DaemonSet1
      namespace: test-ns
    spec:
    <add the spec here>
  - kind: DaemonSet
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    metadata:
      name: DaemonSet2
      namespace: test-ns
    spec:
    <add the spec for second daemonset>
```

I wanted to understand whether this is the correct way to deploy two DaemonSets or not. Since, when I tried deploying the same config, the first DaemonSet came up and running but the second one didn't show up at all.

Comment: You can deploy daemonsets completely independent of each other. They don't need to be applied via a list. Each can have its own manifest. Also, you might consider watching for Kubernetes events to check for pods activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to use list to deploy 2 daemonset. you can just create two differenet daemonset separately.
and if you need create your daemonset's pods in specific node you can just create them with the use of  `spec.template.spec.nodeSelector`  in your `template's spec`. [ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#running-pods-on-select-nodes)

here is the example how you are going to create two different daemonset.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: DaemonSet1
  namespace: test-ns
spec:
    <add the spec here>
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: DaemonSet2
  namespace: test-ns
spec:
    <add the spec for second daemonset>
---
```

Comment: I tried it this way and it works. Also, is there any disadvantage of using "List" over this pattern?

Comment: in k8s ,it's always recommended to create object separately.